# Ruby HTTP Post Request - Content Type?

Tags: ruby, content-type, httprequest

I have the following Method:

```
http_client=Net::HTTP.new(@uri.host,@uri.port)
request=Net::HTTP::Post.new(@uri.request_uri)
request.set_form_data(params)
request.basic_auth(@user,@pass)
result = http_client.request(request)

#
# !!! .content_type does not exist !!!
#
result=case result.content_type
    when "application/json" JSON.parse(result,{:symbolize_names => true})
    when "application/xml" XMLHELPER.parse(result)
end
result
```

So how to determine the content-type that was sent by the server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting a `NoMethodError` from calling `result.content_type` because you've assigned `result` to the response body, which is a string.

```
[...]
response = client.request(request)

result = case response.content_type
    when "application/json" JSON.parse(response.body, {:symbolize_names => true})
    when "application/xml" XMLHELPER.parse(response.body)
end
```

Comment: Sorry. That was my fault. Iv'e just programmed it into the edit Box - next time i'll copy n Paste it ;) -> corrected Version see first post.

Comment: If `result.content_type` is `nil`, the server didn't send one.